# I'm trying to deploy my nodejs(express) api using iisnode on IIS but getting (500 internal server error)

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

The problem i'm facing is that when i'm deploying my api to local test enviroment its working fine but when i deploy it to live https secured server its popping off the error "500 Internal server error"
My web config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="api">
           <match url="api/*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>

      <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <hiddenSegments>
           <add segment="node_modules" />
         </hiddenSegments>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on IIS?

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 500 error.